# dynamically recreate imageviews, labels and buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I started working on an iphone app and since I am not as experienced as most I can not figure out how to recreate dynamically imageviews, labels and buttons. Basically there will be an array in which some data is stored. However the size of the array will vary and such I can not make a static VC on the storyboard. I would like to use the following template and then the array should use this template to recreate it as many times as it needs :

http://www.dropinsight.eu/screenshot1.png

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Cheers

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers about using a UITableView to display each entry in the array as a cell is the way you want to go. To answer your question about "dynamically creating" each item, you would want to create each UI element in your cellForRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
[imageView setTag:1];
[cell addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:X]];
[label setTag:2];
[cell addSubview:label];
[label release];

UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ABC"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setTag:3];
[cell addSubview:button1];
[button1 release];

etc
```

Then in your willDisplayCell method you will set the contents of any UI item that change for each row like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIIamgeView *)[cell viewWithTag:1;
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYZ"]];
[label setText:@"XYZ"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider putting your imageviews, labels and buttons in a `UITableView`.

Rather than use a `UIViewController` in your storyboard, use a `UITableViewController`. This will be the datasource and delegate of the tableView, and can be used to create `UITableViewCell`s. Each cell could contain an imageView, text and 2 buttons per your example

See [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to have some sort of list of items, which can display in detail the information of each item.

I would take a look at UITableView, it is a class meant for displaying multiple rows of data, you can modify its behavior to display a view not unlike the one you describe here.

Xcode has several templates of iOS applications, of which one being an app with a tableview. I suggest opening up a sample project and reading a tutorial like this one: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Your are right this tutorial is a good one.